# Location source settings intent works only with all devices < 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-maps, android-location, android-cursor

Hi below is my code for checking gps settings which works perfectly on all devices with android 2.3.6 and lower , but not in ICS and Jellybean. When i check for GPS settings enabled or not on the device and start the location settings intent and enable the GPS and return to my app , when i check again for GPS it still shows disabled and force closes the app

```
    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

        public Location getLocation() {
                try {





                    locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    // getting GPS status
                    isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    // getting network status
                    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                   // if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
                    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
                    {
                        // no network provider is enabled
                    } else {
                        this.canGetLocation = true;
                        // First get location from Network Provider
                        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("Network", "Network");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                             location = locationManager


                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                        if (isGPSEnabled) {
                            if (location == null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                                if (locationManager != null) {
                                    location = locationManager
                                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                    if (location != null) {
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                return location;
            }





        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }

        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * */
        public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to
                settings menu?");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new 

                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new 
                            Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

And this is what i get in logcat

```
                01-09 14:53:14.190: E/StrictMode(555): class com.android.settings.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity; instances=2; limit=1
01-09 14:53:14.190: E/StrictMode(555): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.settings.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity; instances=2; limit=1
01-09 14:53:14.190: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.<init>(ContentResolver.java:1581)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:320)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at com.android.settings.LocationSettings.onStart(LocationSettings.java:62)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1493)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:981)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1700)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4481)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-09 14:53:14.637: E/StrictMode(555):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 14:53:14.647: W/CursorWrapperInner(555): Cursor finalized without prior close()
01-09 14:53:14.677: E/System(555): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:45)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1586)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.content.ContentQueryMap.close(ContentQueryMap.java:173)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at android.content.ContentQueryMap.finalize(ContentQueryMap.java:179)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
01-09 14:53:14.877: E/System(555):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you are not importing in the wrong settings library. You should be using the `android.provider.Settings` and the `android support library`. It is working find on my GS3 which is v4.2.

Also looking at the LogCat it looks like you have two instances of the LocalSettings running some how. Make sure you are not instantiating two of the same Activity at the same time accessing the phone settings. Strict Mode seems to not like that you have two instances open when it is expecting 1 so it kills your program. I know this might not answer your question but it will probably point you in the right direction.

`StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class LocationSettingsActivity; instances=2; limit=1`

See Also:

[Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

[Android Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

[StrictMode Instance Count Violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956132/android-strictmode-instancecountviolation)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

I was facing this problem because i was trying to access internet on main thread which works with version < 2.3.6 but this is not supported by higher versions, as they Generate Network on Main thread Exception. For this It is always recommended to use Asynctask while using Internet from Your app. Now it works perfectly well with me.