# App Getting Crashed in version 2.2

Tags: android

I create an android App which works perfectly in Android 2.3+ all devices. But when i tried to run in 2.2 but it crashed and gives error in log as,

```
08-16 10:22:41.323: E/dalvikvm(442): Could not find class       'android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder', referenced from method com.uks.android.mssga.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate
08-16 10:22:41.333: W/dalvikvm(442): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 39 (Landroid/os/StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder;) in Lcom/uks/android/mssga/activity/LoginActivity;
08-16 10:22:41.333: D/dalvikvm(442): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000a
08-16 10:22:41.333: D/dalvikvm(442): VFY: dead code 0x000c-009a in Lcom/uks/android/mssga/activity/LoginActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
08-16 10:22:41.423: D/dalvikvm(442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 744 objects / 59064 bytes in 68ms
08-16 10:22:41.483: D/AndroidRuntime(442): Shutting down VM
08-16 10:22:41.483: W/dalvikvm(442): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.uks.android.mssga.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:58)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-16 10:22:41.483: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 10:22:44.503: I/Process(442): Sending signal. PID: 442 SIG: 9
```

Code of LoginActivity is,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            // Other stuff
 }
```

Comment: Please post your `onCreate` code for `LoginActivty`.
As for the exception [StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html) is supported only since API level 9.

Comment: @vKashyap I added code of on create method in edited question check it.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610627/strictmode-for-lower-platform-versions) for using `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder` for lower versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html) was introduced in Android 2.3 (API level 9), so attempts to call it in versions earlier than that will fail.

To stop it crashing on 2.2 and earlier you can choose to either:
* Remove the ThreadPolicy code (as it is a developer debug tool to provide warnings of bad things you are doing)
or
* Use reflection to determine if the class exists before making use of it